# Cant understand how share difficulty affects my chances in solo mining with a pool

Tags: difficulty, solo-mining, mining-pool-shares

So obviously I am not solo mining bitcoin but I think the underlying principles are the same so you guys could help me out here.

I am solo mining ergo on a solo pool (herominers solo pool)

What I do not understand exactly is what **share** difficulty is (not to be mistaken with ergo network difficulty which I understand)

I mean I hash with 2GH/s on ergo I am able to switch between varying share difficulty/vardif(which I have noticed goes up to like 80GH difficulty)  or choose a constant share difficulty.

What I noticed is that if I set that difficulty to 8GH  I get more solo valid shares...

But does this mean that the probability of me finding a block decreases because finding a block needs a higher GH share or something like that ?

I assume that the greater the share difficulty the longer the hash I have to process (so maybe the better changes to solving a correct block? )

Could you explain in detail what share difficulty is and maybe advise me if I should use varying difficulty in my case or a constant (and at which value? )  ?

Comment: Shares are only defined as concept in relation between your hasher and your pool. It has no relation on the probability of your pool as a whole to mine a block; that is controlled by the difficulty.

Comment: @PieterWuille yes but I am solo mining in a solo pool (sounds bizzar I know but it exists) we dont share the blocks we find in other words. The thing is though that manipulating share difficulty I essentially manipulate how many valid shares I submit but how does this affect my chances of finding a block? E.g at 8GH I submit many more shares compared to at e.g 54GH which means many more chances (like submitting more lottery tickets)  but does that maybe mean that because its a smaller hash (8GH) the chance of "getting it right" or find a block decreases?

Comment: It has absolutely nothing to do with your probability of finding a block. It only changes how accurate the pool's idea of your hashrate (and thus affects your share of payout **in case it finds something**) is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mining pool hashrate effect on a miner's income](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10731/mining-pool-hashrate-effect-on-a-miners-income)